# MongoDB Iterate through collection of documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, relationship

I am fairly new to MongoDB. I have created 2 collections, one called "groups" which holds information of each group, and a second called "groupUsers" which is a relational collection that tells which users are connected to a group.

Now, what i am trying to accomplish is first get all the groups the current user is a member of and then, and it is here it goes wrong, get the information from the groups into an array. The error is that I only get the first or the last document into my array. I know that the user has 2 groups connected to him.

Here is how I am trying to accomplish this:

```
var playerID = Spark.getPlayer().getPlayerId();

var dataList = Spark.runtimeCollection('groupUsers');
var myGroups = dataList.find({ user: playerID });
var groups = [];

if( myGroups.hasNext() ) {
    var dataList2 = Spark.runtimeCollection('groups');
    var obj = myGroups.next();

    var thisGroup = dataList2.find({ "_id": {"$oid": ""+obj.group}});

    groups.push(thisGroup);
}

Spark.setScriptData("myUserGroups", groups);
```

Hope this makes sense and someone either can tell me what i am doing wrong or guide me in the right direction :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you have to use 'while' instead of 'if'? As this mentions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36030322/3116810

Comment: Damn you "while"... Thanks :-) Did the job (y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code `var myGroups = dataList.find({ user: playerID })` returns 2 groups then should you not run a loop to fetch `dataList2.find({ "_id": {"$oid": ""+obj.group}});` that many times?

I see you only execute it once.

Comment: while instead of if did the job... Thanks for guiding me on this :-)